# unavailiable assertion methods in python 3.1 unittest

Tags: python, assert, unittest2

I'm new to python programming and especially to unit-testing framework. 
For some reason working with pyDev (py 3.1 interpreter) I cannot use all of those new 
assert methods (such as assertRegexpMatches etc..).

Here's an example code:

class TestParser(unittest.TestCase):

```
    def testskipCommentAndSpaces(self):
        if os.path.isfile(sys.argv[1]):
            #self.vmFilesListPath = sys.argv[1]
            vmFilesListPath = sys.argv[1]
        else:
            #self.vmFilesListPath = get_all_vm_files(sys.argv[1])
            vmFilesListPath = get_all_vm_files(sys.argv[1])
        #parser = Parser(self.vmFilesListPath)
        parser = Parser(vmFilesListPath)
        commands = parser.getCommands()
        for command in commands:
            for token in commands:
                p=re.search(r"(////)",str(token)) 
                **self.assertNotRegexpMatches(str(token),p)**
```

What I get is: AttributeError: 'TestParser' object has no attribute 'assertNotRegexpMatches'
Needless to say that: hasattr(self, 'assertNotRegexpMatches') returns false while the "simple" asserts methods works good.

I'm sure the interpreter is set to 3.1 - i.e  the correct version I need (since I also have py 2.7 installed on my system).

Would thank you for your help,
Igor.L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the `unittest` module in Python 3.1 had an [assertRegexpMatches](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRegexpMatches) method, there is no documented `assertNotRegexpMatches`.  In Python 3.2, `assertRegexpMatches` was renamed to [assertRegex](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRegex) and the complementary `assertNotRegex` was added.

Note that Python 3.1 is obsolete and no longer maintained other than critical security fixes.  There have been many features, fixes, and major performance improvements added in Python 3.2 and now 3.3 which was just released.  Consider upgrading to one of them.

Comment: Hi, thx for your help first of all.   I'd defiantly check the upgrade pack opportunity.  However the weird part is that on python 3.1 - even assertRegexMatches won't work and many other assert methods which actually has documentation on em'.    Meanwhile found a better way using those asserts I need by implementing them Independently of the interpreter version I use. Thanks again!